# Angular Filter, compare JSON file date to today's date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, date

```
<p id="appt_time" ng-if="x.dateTime | date: MM/dd/yyyy == {{todaysDate}}">SHOW ME IF TRUE{{todaysDate}} </p>
```

Plunkr:https://plnkr.co/edit/r2qtcU3vaYIq04c5TVKG?p=preview

`x.dateTime | date: MM/dd/yyyy` gets a date and time which turns out to be when filtered: `06/18/2016` according to my json file.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to compare this "x.dateTime" to today's date and show the paragraph if the statement is true.  So in my angular file, I have a `$scope.todaysDate = "06/18/2016"`, but the paragraph doesn't show.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="x in information">

  <!--Compare Json Object to Javascript Object-->
  <p ng-if ="x.dateTime">{{x.dateTime | date: MM/dd/yyyy }}</p> 
  <!--Compare Json Object to Today's Date-->
<p id="appt_time" ng-if="x.dateTime.valueOf() === todaysDate.valueOf()">Open in: {{todaysDate}} </p>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS File:

```
// declare a module
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
  var todaysDate = new Date();


// configure the module.
// in this example we will create a greeting filter
myAppModule.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) 
{

    $scope.todaysDate = todaysDate;
    $scope.test = "Volvo";

    $http.get("time.json")
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.information = data;
    });
}]
);
```

JSOn file:

```
{
  "dateTime":"2016-06-18T18:41:00.748-04:00"

}
```

Comment: Make `todaysDate` a JavaScript Date object and use `ng-if="x.dateTime.valueOf() === todaysDate.valueOf()"`.

Comment: Hmm, didn't work for me, https://plnkr.co/edit/r2qtcU3vaYIq04c5TVKG?p=preview, any idea if I'm missing anything?

Comment: Can you please post the code to the question itself? I can't see plnkr.co from work. Also, SO requires code in the question.

Comment: I'm guessing `x.dateTime` is not actually a JavaScript Date object.

Comment: Sure, I posted the code

Comment: Ah, okay, it's a string. That changes things :). I'm assuming you want to know if that date and today's date are the same (irrespective of the time portion)?

Comment: Yup, the time portion I would like to find the current time and find the difference between that time and the json file time but I think I can probably figure that out...hopefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're dealing with dates and times, things can get tricky fast. I would suggest using the [Moment.js library](http://momentjs.com), as it makes this super easy:

```
ng-if="moment.utc(x.DateTime).isSame(todaysDate, 'day')"
```

The `"day"` there indicates how granular you want to compare the two values. However, it's relatively easy even without that library:

```
ng-if="x.DateTime.substring(0, 10) === todaysDate"
```

Where you change `$scope.todaysDate` to `"2016-06-18"`.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more. When dealing with dates, Moment.js will avoid so many headaches...

Comment: Awesome that worked!  I ended up using the second piece of code, but I'll look into that moment library.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `validate` function which will return `true` if date is today. Don't forget to inject `$filter`.

```
$scope.validate = function(date) {
   return $filter('date')(date. 'your format') === $filter('date')(new Date(). 'your format');
}
```

In html

```
<p id="appt_time" ng-if="validate(x.dateTime)">SHOW ME IF TRUE{{x.dateTime}} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the foll link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZLJB5i1nQu9RYUV5FAX3?p=preview

// time.json

```
[{
  "dateTime":"2016-06-18T18:41:00.748-04:00"

}]
```

//script.js

```
 $http.get("time.json")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.information = response.data;
        debugger
    });
```

Your problem is solved